# C++ compiler errors compiling libpqxx basic exmaple, what is wrong and how to solve it?

Tags: c++, postgresql, beagleboneblack, libpq, libpqxx

im trying to build the example here https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx#programming-with-libpqxx using c++ compiler on my beagleboneblack, ececuting the command: `g++ -o taks tasks.cpp -lpqxx -lpq`
I belive i have installed the lpqxx library with success.
Gcc compiler version: gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0

When compiling i get the following errors (and several other not show here):

```
 warning: structured bindings only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17
             for (auto [name, salary] : tx.query<std::string, int>(
                       ^
tasks.cpp:20:43: error: ‘using work = class pqxx::transaction<>’ {aka ‘class pqxx::transaction<>’} has no member named ‘query’
             for (auto [name, salary] : tx.query<std::string, int>(
                                           ^~~~~
tasks.cpp:20:60: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
```

The first is a warning, but the others error. Not familiar with C#:

1. What does these errors mean?
2. How do i get on solving them?
3. Is it compiler issues or is it code issues?
4. I just have one file in my direcory and that is copy-paste of the example from the link, am i missing some header files that define some stuff for me?

Comment: The error says it all, you need to enable the `-std=c++17` compiler flag in order to compile the code.

Comment: Ok, so the warning is a actual requirement. So how do i enable -std=c++17? I added my gcc compiler verson to the post. Thanks @NathanOliver

Comment: Just like how you have `-lpqxx` and  `-lpq` in your compile command, you need to add `-std=c++17`

Comment: Just put `-std=c++17` on the same line as gcc

Comment: Or you can install a more recent version of gcc, where C++17 is the assumed standard.

Comment: -std=c++17 warning dissapeared, so that is in the box. But the compiler cant find the member "query" of the class transactions. I haven't specified the connection to the PostgreSQL db yet, will if fail on compiling because of this?

Comment: My guess is that the lpqxx library is old or does not match the example code.

Comment: @drescherjm, you are right, i choose libpqxx 6.4 to get it to compile with my g++ compiler because of language verion i think... How can i undo this? I guess i also need to updated my g++ compiler which is 8.3.0, but what c++ language norm is that using? oO

Comment: According to this https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html GCC 8 (which i have) almost all c++20 Language-featueres is supported. Installing libpqxx i just did configure + make + make install. Is it possible to configure/make/make install and specifying c++ language version doing that? Because it must have used the default version in 8 then i guess?

Comment: `8.3.0` may support c++20 but it's not the default.